# Linux Split on line number for tab delimited file creates 1 blank file

Tags: linux, split

When I run the split command from terminal on a 1.7 million records, it only generates 1 file and it's blank.

Example command:

split -l 300000 my_file.csv

When I use the -b flag and specify Mbs it works but I don't want to use -b because it breaks the lines where the new files start.

Thanks

Comment: Does your CSV file have proper line endings (i.e. not Windows or Mac format)?

Comment: `head -10 my_file.csv | cat -vet` . if you see `^M$` and the end of each line, then convert to unix with `dos2unix my_file.csv`. Good luck.